# golang closure catch wrong value from range

Tags: go

test codes below:

```
func main() {
    lans := [5]string{"java", "python", "erlang", "cpp", "go"}
    fin := make(chan bool)
    for _, l := range(lans) {
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(l)
            }()
    }
     <- fin
}
```

I think the output will be: java, python, erlang, cpp, go;
but the output is:
go  go  go  go  go;
what's wrong here?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just write the function like this, to catch the verb `l` into function

```
 go func(l string) {
     fmt.Println(l)
 }(l)
```